# Is there a way to automatically forward text messages to email?

Tags: iphone, email

Is there a way to automatically forward text messages (received on my iPhone) to email?

Answer (score 4):

Not really ideal but I think that you can setup a Google Voice # that will auto forward to both sms and email - https://support.google.com/voice/answer/160203?hl=en

Comment: I use Google Voice which does that and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is available in the US but I was able to place an automatic copy/forward for text messages on an IPhone to email through an extreme text option offered by the phone service carrier I used in Canada.  Standard text rates applied.  Placing the automatic copy forward required a few easy to follow instructions provided by the phone service carrier.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an app that does this for free?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, for example you could take a look a the following list of products offering this possibility.

An answer from devnullius on GoogleWave:

> Solutions to automatically forward iPhone SMS text messages to email
>   iphone (or at least export as txt pdf csv) Solutions for Windows based
>   computers or MacOS / iOS. Also some references to print the iphone
>   sms's.
>
> Some links with information of interest. Solution(s) not (yet) tested.
>
> http://www.appleiphoneschool.com/2008/12/04/sms2mail-backup-and-sent-texts-to-email/
>
> http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/
>
> http://www.itworld.com/software/63546/how-transfer-sms-iphone-computer
>
> http://www.trickyways.com/2010/09/how-to-backup-iphone-text-messages-on-windows/
>
> http://www.iphoneforums.net/forum/iphone-apps-20/txtforward-like-app-8231/
>
> http://insend.de/
>
> http://www.iphone-sms.com/
>
> !!! best bet, for now...
>   http://www.mobyware.net/iphone-os/txtforward-get-free-6688.html

**Source:** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/altoswindows-2k3/s_ZdTE4FiLQ/LyST7e4tXtsJ

Comment: These are all Backup apps that run on computers and used to store messages as a file on them. There is no app I can see that does what the OP wants.ANd if you actually had looked at the links instead of just coping and pasting you would have seen that. The person whose post you copied evens says as such.