# Is there a way using Shortcuts on an iPhone to forward a text message to another number, if the sender contains an ampersand (&) symbol?

Tags: ios, sms, shortcuts-app

I have a similar problem to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87417/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-forward-text-messages-to-email) one but my problem is more specific.

I have seen in Shortcuts that one can setup an automation: if a text message is from x, do y.

I have the need to forward a text message from a specific user from a service with an ampersand in the from name to other mobile phones. I may need to do this to other numbers going forward.

I haven't got that far as it fails on the first hurdle - I can set the rule of "When Message" and "Sender", however, I can't put the symbol in the name.

I've tried workarounds such as creating a contact that I can put as a sender, however, all the relevant fields only allow for a number, so, it can't link the text message to the contact.

Short of getting a web to text type service, I just wondered if anyone had any ideas here?

Comment: Could you give a fictitious example of the "From name" which is failing?  Icon@Daemon? @IconDaemon? IconDaemon@

Comment: @IconDaemon - Sorry, missed this comment... Yes, it's "M&SBank"